# How do I add a document using mongoose with one field being empty object?

Tags: mongoose

This is my schema:

```
const wlb_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  wlbId: Number,
  wlbName: String,
  color: String,
  coordinates: Object,
  boardId: []
})
```

I want to add a document using this schema, where coordinates would be an empty object. I tried to do it like this:

```
  const wlb = new WLB({
    wlbId: req.body.wlbId,
    wlbName: req.body.wlbName,
    color: req.body.color,
    coordinates: {},
    boardId: req.body.boardId
  })
  wlb.save()
```

It didn't create coordinates key at all. So I asked AI, it told me to omit coordinates:

```
  const wlb = new WLB({
    wlbId: req.body.wlbId,
    wlbName: req.body.wlbName,
    color: req.body.color,
    boardId: req.body.boardId
  })
  wlb.save()
```

It also didn't create coordinates key at all.
I am now using a workaround:

```
  const wlb = new WLB({
    wlbId: req.body.wlbId,
    wlbName: req.body.wlbName,
    color: req.body.color,
    coordinates: {
      something: "i needed to insert this here"
    },
    boardId: req.body.boardId
  })
  wlb.save()
```

Is there a way to create coordinates as empty object? Or do I need to use this idiotic workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongo does not save empty objects by default. It is done to save storage. YOu can override this behaviour by using [`minimize`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#minimize).

```
const wlb_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  wlbId: Number,
  wlbName: String,
  color: String,
  coordinates: Object,
  boardId: []
}, { minimize: false })
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@Tushar Shahi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10140124/tushar-shahi) has already stated the `{ minimize: false }` will allow you to save empty objects.

However, if you add a `default` to the `coordinates` property you can omit the property all together when you first create the document and the empty object will be inserted. This is more semantic to someone reading your schema i.e. you intend to save an empty object by deafult and it wasn't a coding error. It would look like so:

```js
const wlb_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    wlbId: Number,
    wlbName: String,
    color: String,
    coordinates: {
        type: Object,
        default: {} // <Add default empty object
    },
    boardId: []
},{minimize: false}); //< Add this options object
```

Then when you create:

```js
const wlb = new WLB({
    wlbId: req.body.wlbId,
    wlbName: req.body.wlbName,
    color: req.body.color,
    //< You can omit the coordinates so that the default empty object is inserted
    boardId: req.body.boardId
})
await wlb.save()
```